# overriding JComboBox getSelectedItem is not working

Tags: java, overriding, jcombobox

I m trying to override my JComboBox getSelectedItem method using this static method :

```
public static void setupID_TITLE_ComboBox(JComboBox jComboBox, String tableName) throws SQLException {
    // query to select ID and TITLE from profiles table
    String query = "SELECT ID,TITRE FROM " + tableName + ";";
    ResultSet myJComboResultSet = SQLTools.ExecuteQuery(query);
    
    ArrayList visualItems = new ArrayList(); // the Items of my combobox  [item1,item2]
    ArrayList idItems = new ArrayList(); // the corresponding IDs for each item [id1,id2]

    while (myJComboResultSet.next()) {
        visualItems.add(myJComboResultSet.getObject("TITRE")); // filling items set
        idItems.add(myJComboResultSet.getObject("ID")); // filling IDs set
    }
    
    System.out.println("IDItems=" + idItems); // checking that my Items are filled
    System.out.println("visualItems=" + visualItems); // checking that my IDs are filled
    
// creating a combobox of previous items
    jComboBox = new JComboBox(visualItems.toArray()) {
        ArrayList values = idItems;

// overriding the getSelectedItem to return the corresponding selected item's ID
        @Override
        public Object getSelectedItem() {
            Object get = values.get(super.getSelectedIndex());
            System.out.println("get = " + get);
            return get; 
        }

    };

}
```

I m calling this method from another frame :

```
   JComboBoxTools.setupID_TITLE_ComboBox(J_Users_Profile,"profiles");
```

But when executed it don't work.
the output :

> visualItems=[Admin,Teacher,Student]
>
> IDItems=[0,3,5]
>
> the selected item return value is : Teacher

Don't know what to do I want it to return 3 wich is the ID of teacher.

the full project is under : [this link](https://github.com/MHTaleb/Encologim)

thank you.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to achieve here? You just want to print the selected value?

Comment: my combobox items are [SuperAdmin,Student,Teacher] when an item is selected the return values is for example (Student) in my database Student profile have an id, I want to process in backend using the id not the title value of the profile wich is (Student) that why i have 2 arraylist one for visual (frontend) one for processing (I will generate a insert query in the backend)

Comment: my query is well formated and generated but i want the id not the profile title

Comment: i m using getSelectedItem to get the selected (front end item) but i need the id not the string value

Comment: the `getSelectedIndex()` will only return 0, 1 or 2 in your case. I bet that's not matching your db id...

Comment: that why [values.get(super.getSelectedIndex())] is my dba ID, as you see in  [ArrayList values = idItems;] where idItems is filled with my IDs

Comment: Maybe you could try using `super.getSelectedIndex();` in stead of `values.get(super.getSelectedIndex());`.

Comment: the solution was in using a mapComboBoxModel with some overriding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my desired values using a mapComboBoxModel

```
public static void setupID_TITLE_ComboBox(JComboBox jComboBox, String tableName) throws SQLException {

    String query = "SELECT ID,TITRE FROM " + tableName + ";";
    ResultSet myJComboResultSet = SQLTools.ExecuteQuery(query);

    HashMap myMap = new HashMap();
    while (myJComboResultSet.next()) {  
        myMap.put(myJComboResultSet.getObject("TITRE"), myJComboResultSet.getObject("ID"));
    }

    jComboBox.setModel(new MapComboBoxModel(myMap) {

        @Override
        public Object getValue(Object selectedItem) {
            return map_data.get(selectedItem); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    });


}
```

I overrided getValue to return the ID .

```
if (myComponent instanceof JComboBox) {
            JComboBox jComboBox = (JComboBox) myComponent;
             MapComboBoxModel model = (MapComboBoxModel) jComboBox.getModel();
             values+=""+model.getValue(model.getSelectedItem())+",";                
        }
```